# How to embed php in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Face problem when writing PHP syntax in javascript syntax.

```
var id = $("#data-1").val();
var url = '<?= base_url('home/alone/'); ?>.'id'';
console.log(url);
```

I need to place the id at the end of url. But my code is not working. What is wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Too many single quotes and use `+` in JS to concatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use " instead of ' like this:

```
var id = $("#data-1").val();
var url = "<?= base_url('home/alone/'); ?>" + id;
console.log(url)
```